# Open/Save as matplotlib own format?

Tags: python, svg, vector, matplotlib

When you plot something with matplotlib a viewer pops up.
You can zoom and pan you image. It is vector image because you can zoom as much as you like.
If you save the image as : svg, eps or png the result is not as good as the one in the matplotlib-own-viewer.

Is there way to save it in whatever matplotlib is using to display and then open it in the matplotlib-viewer later??

thanks

PS> if not at least if there is a way to make the svg-lines thinner !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a vector image, the viewer is continuously rendering a view of the data in the plot, you know? If you zoom in on the svg; you're still zooming in: the lines had a thickness before so they're going to get thicker the more you zoom in. 
What you could do is have your script write the necessary code to a new script (with .py extension) so you can just open that and get the plot you want again. After all, matplotlib kind of uses python to "display" so in a way that is really the only answer to your question :-)

let's say you have

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,4,9,16,25]
d = open("plotly.py","w")
d.write("from pylab import *\nx = %s\ny=%s\nplot(x,y)\nshow()"%(a,b))
d.close()
```

You could generalize that a bit; but that would be the gist I think. Have fun!

Comment: clever... based on your advice, I save my data to pickle and then wrote pylab-script to show it. thanks

Comment: Oh yeah pickle is really nice. I vaguely remember trying this with some really long lists but they got truncated somehow iirc... Pickle is probably better behaved in that respect. Thanks!